# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gspread'

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, gspread

I have an issue with the gspread module, and I think with Python 3 too.

My code is something like that: `import blabla, gspread, etc...`

And if I try to run it `python3 myscript.py` every module seems to run fine, except gspread. I receive this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "z_schedule.py", line 3, in <module>
    from z_database import *
  File "/home/pi/Projects/InstaPy/z_database.py", line 3, in <module>
    import gspread, gspread_formatting
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gspread'
```

I'm running python3 and I installed gspread both with `pip` and `pip3`. I also installed oauth2 in the same way.

My code used to work great until I updated my Raspberry, InstaPy and Python 3. Somebody knows how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: the same settings (environment, IDE, terminal, ...) where you execute the script: could you verify you have it installed by typing `pip freeze | grep gspread` and post the output please?

Comment: `pip freeze` gave me a bunch of module versions like: `googleapis-common-protos==1.5.3, gspread==3.1.0, gspread-formatting==0.0.3, httplib2==0.12.1, oauth2client==4.1.3, oauthlib==2.0.1, regex==2019.2.7, requests==2.21.0, requests-oauthlib==0.7.0`

Comment: `grep gspread` gave me nothing. Empty line :(

Comment: you should execute the total "`pip freeze | grep gspread`" for filtering the relevant stuff. But that's fine, your first comment gave the hint that gspread seems to be installed properly in your current working virtualenvironment...

Comment: Oh yes, now I see only gspead and gspead_formatting bold red, but still: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gspread'` if I run the script

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
pip3 install gspread
```

and run the script again. I hope it helps to solve the problem